# How to turn json to case class when case class has only one field

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1

In play 2.1 reads are used to marshall Json to objects. But how can I do this when the case class has only one field. The ideom that works for more fields does not work, as with one field 'and' is not used. Thus I do not get a FunctionBuilder.

The following code gives me a type mismatch. How can I fix this?

```
case class Data(stamm: Seq[String])


implicit val dataReads  = (
  (__ \ "stamm").read(Reads.list[String])
)(Data)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Json combinators doesn't work for single field case class.

Pascal (writer of this API) has explained this situation here
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!starred/play-framework/hGrveOkbJ6U

There are some workarounds which works, like this one:

```
case class A(value: List[Int])
val areads = (__ \ 'value).read[List[Int]].map{ l => A(l) } // covariant map
```

Answer (score 48):

As Julien answered, you can read single field case classes using this:

```
case class Person(name: String)

val personReads: Reads[Person] = 
  (__ \ "name").read[String].map { name => Person(name) }
```

Just a complement, if you want to write:

```
val personWrites: Writes[Person] = 
  (__ \ "name").write[String].contramap { (person: Person) => person.name }
```

Or format (read and write):

```
val personFormat: Format[Person] = 
  (__ \ "name").format[String].inmap(name => Person(name), (person: Person) => person.name)
```

For write and format you have to import this:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
```

Comment: Reading the above, in the personWrites example, should (name: Person) be (person: Person) ?

Comment: Thanks man! You've saved a lot my time. But the question is how people design libraries - why this simple thing is not working with the same approach as with many fields %)

Answer (score 8):

Based on @yokomizor's answer, I found the simplest solution to create a `Formatter` to be

```
case class Person(name: String)
val personFormatter: Format[Person] =
  (__ \ "full_name").format[String].inmap(Person.apply, unlift(Person.unapply))
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler solution than the accepted one:

```
case class A(value: String)
val reads = (__ \ "key").read[String].map(A.apply)
```