# How to parse json with a single field in Playframework2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to parse a [Travis-ci api response](http://docs.travis-ci.com/api/#repositories) which has the following structure :

```
{
    repos: [
          {"id": ..., "slug": ...}, 
          {"id": ..., "slug": ...}, 
          {"id": ..., "slug": ...}
    ]
}
```

So I have decided to create case classes reflecting the json structure :

```
case class TravisRepository(id: String, slug: String)
case class TravisUserRepositories(repos: Seq[TravisRepository])
```

And I have added the implicit Read methods :

```
implicit val travisRepositoryReads: Reads[TravisRepository] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "slug").read[String]
)(TravisRepository.apply _)

implicit val travisUserRepositoriesReads: Reads[TravisUserRepositories] = (
    (JsPath \ "repos").read[Seq[TravisReposity]]
)(TravisUserRepositories.apply _)
```

However the second read is not compiling with the following error :

```
Overloaded method value [read] cannot be applied to (Seq[utils.TravisRepository] => utils.TravisUserRepositories)
```

When adding another column to the second Read, this compiles. With a single column, this is not compiling anymore. Can someone explain why is this not compiling? Is it a limitation of the Play-Json parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply because you have the case "only one single field in your case class"...
To be able to use the Functional combining, you need at least 2 fields.

> // would be OK implicit val travisUserRepositoriesReads:
>   Reads[TravisUserRepositories] = (
>       (JsPath \ "repos").read[Seq[TravisReposity]] and
>       ... )(TravisUserRepositories.apply _)
>
> // should be OK implicit val travisUserRepositoriesReads:
>   Reads[TravisUserRepositories] = (
>       (JsPath \ "repos").read[Seq[TravisReposity]] map (TravisUserRepositories.apply _)

Comment: Indeed, just found : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754092/how-to-turn-json-to-case-class-when-case-class-has-only-one-field. Thanks a lot.